# NHibernate - Second level collection caching inconsistency

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I'm using second level caching (SysCache), with NHibernate 3.2. I'm deleting the collection and writing new elements on it in the same transaction. However, this breaks the cache, as it stills hold references to the deleted elements. Transaction code:

```
 RepositorioMovimentacao.Delete(notaHibernate.MovimentacaoItemEquipList);
 RepositorioNota.Update(notaHibernate);
 RepositorioMovimentacao.Save(model.MovimentacaoItemEquipList);
 Session.Commit()
```

Exception thrown when retrieving the entity on a different session:

```
No row with the given identifier ...
```

Here is my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="CMD.Business.BusinessEntity" namespace="CMD.Business.BusinessEntity.Entities">
  <class name="NotaMovimentacaoEquipamento" table="CEM.NOTA_MOVIMENTACAO_EQUIPAMENTO" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" >
    <cache  usage="read-write"/>
...
    <bag name="MovimentacaoItemEquipList" inverse="true" generic="true" lazy="true" >
      <cache  usage="read-write"/>
      <key>
        <column name="NTMO_SQ_NOTA_MOVIMENTACAO"/>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="MovimentacaoItemEquip" />
    </bag>
...
```

The many-to-one mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="CMD.Business.BusinessEntity" namespace="CMD.Business.BusinessEntity.Entities">
    <class name="MovimentacaoItemEquip" table="CEM.MOVIMENTACAO_ITEM_EQUIP" lazy="true" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true" >
    <cache  usage="read-write"/>
...
  <many-to-one name="NotaMovimentacaoEquipamento" class="NotaMovimentacaoEquipamento">
      <column name="NTMO_SQ_NOTA_MOVIMENTACAO" />
    </many-to-one>
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. When deleting a collection of a parent, always set the parents collection to null before commiting.

Example:

```
ChildRepository.Delete(parent.ChildList)
parent.ChildList = null;
```

Not doing this was causing the cache to get corrupted.